# List of dates from a view

Tags: sql, oracle, date, view

Ok this is a similar problem like the one I had before but it has the requirment that it needs to be a view with 1 variable and it needs to be as simple as possible.
I need a view that generates a list of dates within a given month (that is the variable).

Here is what I have so far:

```
create view monthview(datesetter) as (   
select
to_date(to_date(datesetter),'MM.YYYY')-1 + level as DateRange
from
dual
where
(to_date(to_date(datesetter),'MM.YYYY')-1+level) <= sysdate
connect by level<=31);
```

and the view should than be called by something like:

```
select * from monthview where datesetter='02.2008';
```

and then generate a list like

```
01.02.2007
02.02.2007
```

and so on

It either tells me that I can't compile the view due to the fact that there is a mistake when I use datesetter or it compiles the view but then it tells me thata there is a non numeric value where a numeric one is needed when I use 'datesetter' ....

Thanks for any ideas or help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try a pipelined function:

```
create or replace type date_array_type as table of date;

create or replace function monthview (datesetter varchar2) return date_array_type
pipelined as

cursor c is 
select to_date(level || '.' || datesetter , 'dd.mm.yyyy') dt
from dual
connect by level <= to_number(to_char(
  last_day(to_date(datesetter , 'mm.yyyy')), 'dd'));

begin

for r in c loop

  pipe row(r.dt);

end loop;

return;

end;
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
select * from table( monthview('03.2012'));
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fa085/1) is a fiddle

Comment: Hmm you're right that works great but my aim, if possible and I am having doubts that it is, that I want this to work in a view. Any ideas how that could work?

Comment: @Thevagabond, then maybe this post may help http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:906341500346611919

Comment: Seems that it is not possible to do this in a view then... oh well :-) then thanks for your function. It will do the job just fine :-)